# How to get both headers and JSON return with parameter in Angular 6

Tags: wordpress, angular, wordpress-rest-api

I am using Angular http request to get a JSON response from a wordpress rest API. When I pass a parameter I do not get a response, but without the parameter it is working fine.

Here is my code from **wpgetpost.service.ts** file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { GlobalService } from '../global/global.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WpgetpostService {
  constructor( private http: HttpClient, private URL: GlobalService ) { }
  getPost(): Observable<any[]> {
    const url = this.URL.WP_API_URL;
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url, {
      params: {
        page: '2'
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Also, how can I get the headers from this response?

Answer (score -1):

as per WP documentation. 
using the param within the same URL.

`/wp/v2/posts?page=2`

Comment: What is a network response for /wp/v2/posts?page=2 in network tab?